# TSP using python

Tags: python, traveling-salesman

I'm given homework to come up with the python program to solve Travellers salesman problem. In the class they explained how it should work and showed one example.

```
path_map = [[0,10,15,20],
        [5,0,9,10],
        [6,13,0,12],
        [8,8,9,0]]
```

It is an example map
I thought it is popular problem and I can find algorithms to solve this problem in the internet. But I couldn't. I tried my own version. But I failed. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is what I have so far

```
class TSP:

def __init__(self, init, path_map):
    self.init = init
    self.cost = 0
    self.path_map = path_map
    self.vertices = [i for i in range(1,len(path_map)+1)]

def min_path(self, start):
    if not self.vertices:
        return self.path_map[start-1][init-1]
    else:
        m = [i for i in range(len(self.vertices)+1)]
        i=0
        for v in self.vertices:
            tv = self.vertices.pop(v-1)
            m[i]=self.cost + self.min_path(v)
            self.vertices.insert(v-1,tv)
            i = i + 1
        self.cost = self.cost + min(m)

    return cost `
```

What I get, when i try to run it:

```
>>> t = TSP(1,path_map)
>>> t.min_path(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    t.min_path(1)
  File "/home/wanhrust/python/TSP.py", line 42, in min_path
    m[i]=self.cost + self.min_path(v)
  File "/home/wanhrust/python/TSP.py", line 42, in min_path
    m[i]=self.cost + self.min_path(v)
  File "/home/wanhrust/python/TSP.py", line 42, in min_path
    m[i]=self.cost + self.min_path(v)
  File "/home/wanhrust/python/TSP.py", line 41, in min_path
    tv = self.vertices.pop(v)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

Comment: Has your instructor mentioned about "graphs" or "graph theory" ?

Comment: What do you mean by "you failed"? Does it run? Does it give exceptions? Does it sometimes give the correct solution? Do you have weird bugs? What exactly is the problem you have?

Comment: Yeah. He mentioned Graph Theory. We gonna start it next lecture. This program gives error. Have added error in my Question

Answer (score 1):

1. Generate loads of random solutions.
2. Sort those solutions by length.
3. Delete the worst 50%
4. Combine the best 50% with each other in some way (splice them together)
5. Goto 2.

Repeat this until you have a stable solution. It (almost certainly) won't be optimal, but it'll be much much better than random.

Comment: Thanks. But the task is to find the best one

Comment: You should also mention the requirement for finding the best solution in your question, as for the TSP that means something quite significant.

Answer (score 0):

IndexError: pop index out of range - cases when the iteration index doesn't exist the list, for example list = [1,2,3], have 3 elements, and you try to get list[10], you'll get that error